# Consideration about putting a SVN server and the CI server on the same machine

Tags: svn, jenkins, server, visualsvn-server

I have to migrate our CI server (Jenkins) and our SVN server (VisualSVN) away from the VMs they are running on. I have been thinking to put both on the same machine and I am trying to find some counter-arguments to this (not just for the sake of not doing it, but to make sure I have considered all aspects).

Until now I did not find anything specific, except the obvious few:

- Set proper binding to avoid conflicts
- Have a big enough disk to hold repos, CI builds and artifacts
- Understand that when the machine goes down it bringd down both services

But nothing that is specific to using SVN and Jenkins on the same box. I am assuming Jenkins will still connect to the repo through http although it will be pointed at `localhost`.

Does anyone have any other ideas for or against this setup?

P.S.: bonus question: I also have a NuGet server running through IIS on the same machine where Jenkins is, which will need to be moved as well and will probably end up on the same server, so any tips for this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to have a separate server for Jenkins.

If you want to maintain a good level of performance for your Jenkins application, running a SVN server on the same host will not help (regarding the CPU or the R/W operations on the disk).

If your Jenkins instance is hosting a lot of jobs and if you experience some performance issues, having SVN running on the same machine will not help to solve your performance problems.

If you have to upgrade your SVN server version and if you have to restart the host, it will also impact your Jenkins application.

If you want to protect your Jenkins instance with Nginx (or another reverse proxy), maybe it will be easier if Jenkins is running on its own host (without SVN).